# Unsatisfied Link Error Help Java JNI Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, java-native-interface, wrapper, native-methods

Hi I am trying to run a project in eclipse and am getting the runtime error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: mywrapperclass.nativemethod()V

I only get the error code when I call a native method in the wrapper class from my main. I have looked around on many forums and blogs/websites and haven't been able to fix this. Debug and my browsing have me led me to thinking that the problem lies in the project not being able to find the native methods within the dll.

I had a lot of trouble getting eclipse to find the .dll and eventually solved this by placing the dll in the system32 folder.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

> Project > Properties > Java Build Path

Click on the arrow of the JAR that needs the DLL library.

> Native library location

You have to specify the location of the DLL library.

Comment: Where would I find the JAR that needs the DLL in the Java Build Path window? Is it under the source tab? In the source window i see my projectname/src, which i have then opened to find native library locatinon, and then have specified to the .dll location and none of the directories I have tried have worked

Comment: I was able to remove the UnsatisfiedLinkError by going to the Java Build Path, add the source folder with my so files, then click the arrow on that folder and add the same folder to the Native library location setting, as described above.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to bundle the dlls with eclipse plugin is

create a folder structure under the plugin like this "os/win32/x86" for x86 architecture and place your dlls there.

and load the libraries like this in your plugin code System.loadLibrary("Dll name");

Comment: It seems to find my dll it just cant access the native methods it needs to find...does it need the .exp .lib .pdb files with it? They all exist in the project alongside one another...

Answer (score 0):

1. open .classpath in the project location
2. Set the dll path as "value" for "CLASSPATH_ATTR_LIBRARY_PATH_ENTRY" attribute